# How to improve this table stability?

Tags: table

I built this tall wooden table for working while standing. The problem is that it's a little bit unstable(shaky) horizontally. What is the minimum work I can do to make it stable?

[image: table]
[image: table2]

Edit: Diagonal bracings on sides successfully worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The minimum would be diagonal bracing on back and side.

```
+---+
|  /|
| / |   
|/  |
+---+
```

Triangles resist lateral forces much better than rectangles do.

Comment: And a few braces in the front corners which I think it where it is weakest.

Answer (score 6):

You could add some very large steel L brackets to brace the legs and try to stiffen them a bit, but it would still be somewhat shakey.  The "right" way to fix this is to use "cross bracing".  The two cross members you have on the back should be diagonal instead of horizontal.  Diagonal cross members prevent the side-to-side wobble that makes your table feel unstable.

This image isn't a table but it does illustrate the concept:

[image]

One diagonal brace will help, but two will give the most stiffness.  You can add these in addition to the horizontal pieces you already have.

Answer (score 4):

Just in basic table design you are missing the horizontal supports right under your table top.

The first three horizontal supports are not only too low, too thin, but they are also installed wrong.  You have them going across the table legs.  If they were inside the table legs the tables would be set to a fix point.  As it stands you have created a flex point and it will loosen over time.

You can keep the design aspects the same.  But simply adding a 3-4 inch piece (4 pieces total) right under the top and in between each leg will really change the performance.

If you just google images of "tables" you will see many like yours without cross support.  Notice that almost all have the four stabilizers at the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options to stabilize your bench. #1 add a L bracket at the top of each back leg and secure to the wall it looks like OSB so it should be very stable even if no studs are in that location. #2 add X bracing to the back legs if it tends to wobble front to back adding X bracing to the back to front on each side should keep it from moving.
I like #1 but if you want to be able to move it around #2 would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Leg levelers come in various sizes and shape (e.g., [http://www.amazon.com/Combination-Leg-Equalizer-Set-4/dp/B001DT32PC/ref=pd_sim_sbs_200_2?ie=UTF8&dpID=41%2Bdv2zCIzL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=1Z948VXVGHBJCVBS8T39](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DT32PC)).  Of course, you could just use a shim under one leg so all 4 meet the floor at the same time.

Comment: I don't think that's the question being asked, here. The problem seems to be that the table flexes, not that only three legs touch the floor.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.  The first is to create a Tbrace - or a cross brace which is pretty much the same thing.  This will create stability.

The other option is to take a 1 11/2 inch drill bit, drill a whole half way through - take 3 inch screws, drill it in to the sides, fill the holes with wood putty.  Or if you are fancy get a special drill bit and cut out plugs of the same type of wood and then glue those plugs in (stop plugs)

Comment: How/where for the Tbrace?  What is  a "1 11/2 inch drill bit"?  Why 3" screws?  into the sides of what?